# Selecting Parent's Sibling's content

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

Below is the code I am working on, my goal is, whenever the user click the link with a class "click_me", I would like to alert the content of it's parent's siblings, which is "Hello Friends" or "How are you?".

I've tried doing the code below, but it didn't work.

```
 $('.click_me').click(function(event){
                    alert($(this).parent('div').closest('p').html());
                });



<li>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="click_me">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    <p>Hello Friends!</p>
</li>


<li>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="click_me">Click Me</a>
    </div>
    <p>How are you?!</p>
</li>
```

Comment: You put the solution is in the title of the question.

Answer (score 2):

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will look for only the ancestor elements, in your case the `p` element is not an ancestor element, it is a sibling

you need to use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
alert($(this).parent('div').siblings('p').html());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j87nF/)

or in this case it is the next element use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
alert($(this).parent('div').next('p').html());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gRzTG/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to select the next element of its parent. Issue with your selector is that you are looking upwards using `closest` which tests itself and up the DOM tree.

```
alert($(this).closest('div').next().html());
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YTE8q/)**